# Material UI multi-select initial values not correctly displayed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am pretty new to MUI and have encountered an issue when using an editing form and displaying values from database in  the Select component. Some of the values are displayed, but some, even though they are in the initial value array(if I console log, they are printed), are just not displayed and it's just random which aren't showed on every new entry - so I suppose somehow the select is not behaving correctly? (if I post the form, they are posted as values). I used the same form (except the initial values were empty) for creating and everything seems to work fine. So the main problem is just some values are not displaying, but for example, if I select the same time and then post the form, then two rows with the same time will be posted (so I can't see it or deselect it even).
Below is the select code (Since there are a few same selects for different days, showing only one):

```
return (...
 <Grid item xs={12}>
            <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 802.03 }}>
              <InputLabel id="monday_select">Monday times</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="monday_select"
                fullWidth
                id="monday_select"
                value={daysObject.mondayValue}
                multiple
                onChange={handleChangeMultipleMonday}
                input={<OutlinedInput label="Monday times" />}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
              >
                {daysObject.timeSelectValue.map((time) => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={time}
                    value={time}
                    style={getStyles(time, daysObject.mondayValue, theme)}
                  >
                    {time}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
)

const handleChangeMultipleMonday = (
    event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof daysObject.mondayValue>
  ) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    daysObject.handleMonday(
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };
)
```

The daysObject is an object filled with props to pass since this is a stepper form. It looks like this:

```
const daysObject: IDaysObject = {
   timeSelectValue: timeInterv,
   mondayValue: mondayInterval,
   handleMonday: setMondayInterval,
   tuesdayValue: tuesdayInterval,
   handleTuesday: setTuesdayInterval,
   wednesdayValue: wednesdayInterval,
   handleWednesday: setWednesdayInterval,
   thursdayValue: thursdayInterval,
   handleThursday: setThursdayInterval,
   fridayValue: fridayInterval,
   handleFriday: setFridayInterval,
   saturdayValue: saturdayInterval,
   handleSaturday: setSaturdayInterval,
   sundayValue: sundayInterval,
   handleSunday: setSundayInterval,
 };
```

The mondayValue is a string array of monday time intervals (from database) and timeSelectValue is a string array of all selectable time intervals.

[This is how the form with not fully populated times looks like (for ex. monday is empty, some other times have not all times that should be there)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXdE4.png)

[And these are the monday times that should be shown (6:00-9:00 and 9:00-12:00)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2eIA.png)

This is my first time asking a question so please let me know if I can improve in describing/showing somehow.

EDIT: Tried using the renderValue option in the select:

```
  <Select
                labelId="monday_select"
                fullWidth
                id="monday_select"
                value={daysObject.mondayValue}
                multiple
                onChange={handleChangeMultipleMonday}
                input={<OutlinedInput label="Monday times" />}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
                renderValue={(value) => (
                  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
                    {value.map((value) => (
                      <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                    ))}
                  </Box>
                )}
              >
                {daysObject.timeSelectValue.map((time) => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={time}
                    value={time}
                    style={getStyles(time, daysObject.mondayValue, theme)}
                  >
                    {time}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
```

This way it displays the values, however they are not marked as selected, and cannot be controlled:
[Displayed but not controlled values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkRqD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I realised that the problem was only with two time intervals - 6:00 - 9:00 and 9:00 - 12:00. This wasn't a problem with the MUI multi-select but the formatting itself - the times were 6:00 - 9:00 and 9:00 - 12:00 in the time array, but the database would save them as 06:00 - 09:00 and 09:00 - 12:00 and so the select woudln't behave as it should.